# Query START_DATE is 1 day greater than the END_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table where i have two columns START_DATE and END_DATE. I need to find out all the records where start date is 1 day greater than end date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from myTable
 where end_date = start_date + 1
```

will show you all the rows where `end_date` is exactly 1 day later than `start_date`.

Be aware that Oracle `date` columns always have a day and a time component, though, even if your front end isn't showing the time component.  If `end_date` and `start_date` always have a time component of midnight, they might be exactly 1 day apart.  If they have actual times, though, it is very unlikely that they would be exactly 1 day apart.  If you really want to see all rows where the day component differs by a day, ignoring the time component

```
select *
  from myTable
 where trunc(end_date) = trunc(start_date) + 1
```